# Meteor-Up Issue Mup Deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-up

I'm trying to deploy using mup, I've done mup setup which seemed to work, unfortunately mup deploy does not work. Here is the log of my issue:

[image: log]

I know most of the issues of this are a result of not doing mup setup, but I have done that so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your mup.json another issue that comes up is spacing between your apps name.

If you look at app name make sure there are no spaces or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a sample of your `mup.json` so I can only guess. I had a similar issue when I was not setting the *"app"* key properly. Make sure you reference your app's root folder properly as absolute or use the `.` (as in, this current directory) like:

```
{ 
  ...

  "app": '.',
}
```